# How to revert a git checkout masTER?

Tags: git

I was on a test branch and by mistake I run

```
git checkout masTER
```

It renames my master branch to masTER. When I run `git branch`, I obtain:

```
masTER
test
```

If I run `git checkout test` and then `git checkout master`. The master branch doesn't retrieve its original capitalization.

How can I revert this mistake, and why does this happen?

P.S: I use git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)

P.S2: I'm using OS X 10.11.6 which use Journaled HFS+ and is case-insensitive by default. If I run:

```
touch abc
touch abC
```

Running `ls ab*` gives only

```
abc
```

Comment: Remove the branch localy and checkout again?

Comment: Yeah. Did you tried `git branch -D masTER`, `git checkout master`? I assume your `masTER` branch does not have local changes?

Comment: Name and version of the operating system?

Comment: @Agostino: it's mentioned. In any case - I do not think it matters.

Comment: `masTER` branch has local changes.

Comment: Ok, in this case what about `git branch -m masTER titties`, `git checkout master`?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs You mean "Apple Git-66"? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Agostino Yes, it's mac, case sensitive system. This is all that matters.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs New Macs are configured to be case INsensitive, even though it's a quasi-UNIX OS.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs good technical answer, but negative style points for variable naming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Defining the problem

This problem occurs on any case-preserving but case-insensitive file system.  By default, then, it occurs on Macs and Windows boxes, and not on Linux and the like.

Git itself is case-sensitive, pretty much everywhere.  A file named `master.txt` is independent of one named `masTER.txt`, and therefore a Git *tree* object will keep the two as separate items, and Git's index (also known as the cache or the staging-area) considers these separate files.  There is a `core.ignoreCase` setting in `git config` meant to help it recognize when the underlying OS disagrees, but in general Git thinks of these as different.

Since these file names are stored inside files—repository objects of type *tree*, stored in `.git/objects/`, and Git's index, stored in `.git/index`<sup>1</sup>—and not merely handed over to the OS to store, they can *be*, and therefore are, case-sensitive, even if the OS is not.<sup>2</sup>

This is true for branch names, and remote-tracking branch and tag names, as well.  Since these names are kept in the file `.git/packed-refs`, they can be case-sensitive.  (Git also stores its idea of your *current* branch in `.git/HEAD`, as a text string, which is therefore case-sensitive.)  But these names are not *always* kept in `.git/packed-refs`.  In fact, they're often *not* in `.git/packed-refs` at all.  An *active* branch name—one that is being modified—winds up stored in an individual file in `.git/refs/heads/`, such as `.git/refs/heads/master`.  An *active* remote-tracking branch name winds up in `.git/refs/remotes/`, e.g., `.git/refs/remote/origin/master`.

If the OS is case-insensitive, this means that branches named `master` and `masTER` are *different* when they're packed, but become *the same* once they become active!

It gets worse though.  A name that was inactive gets packed: moved into `.git/packed-refs`.  If the name now *becomes* active, it appears in *both* `.git/packed-refs` *and* (assuming it's a *branch* name) `.git/refs/heads/`.  This means that an inactive name is case-sensitive, and an active name is case-insensitive, and you can get both happening at the same time so that you have a `masTER` and a `master` that are different (because both appear in `.git/packed-refs` where we can tell them apart) *and*, simultaneously, the same!  What this means—how Git behaves when you're in this bizarre Schrödinger's-cat<sup>3</sup> situation—is not at all clear.  Obviously it's a bad idea, though.  (I managed to put my test repo into this state where I had both `master` *and* `masTER` by doing `git pack-refs --all` and then `git checkout -b masTER`.  I did not push it any further though.)

#### Fixing it

The OSes (see footnote 2 again) presenting the problem today are case-*insensitive* but case-*preserving*.  This means that once you have a file named `masTER`, attempts to use or create a file named `master`, `Master`, `MASTER`, `mAsTeR`, and so on, all refer instead to the existing file `masTER`.<sup>4</sup>

Some of these OSes allow you to rename the file with just a case-change (`mv masTER master` for instance), so `git branch -m masTER master` *might* do the trick, if Git would just issue an OS-level "rename" operation.  Alas, in practice Git checks first, and finds that it can access a branch named `master` (which is of course the file named `masTER`):

```
$ git branch -m masTER master
fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.
```

Hence, the fix is to rename the branch *twice*.  First we move it to a name that the OS *cannot* find, that does not match any existing case-folded branch names.  You can just pick any unlikely name and hope it is not in use, or you can run `git branch` (or `git for-each-ref refs/heads`) to check whether the unlikely name you just picked is in fact in use.  In any case, if you rename the current (wrong-case) branch to this new unused name that *does not*, even under silly case-folding rules, match some existing name, that will, as a side effect, delete the old, wrong-case-but-OS-insists-on-matching-it name entirely:

```
$ git branch -m masTER tmp
```

Now that the old "wrong-case-but" name is thoroughly eradicated, *now* you can rename the branch back, with the correct case:

```
$ git branch -m tmp master
```

Note that this also takes care of stripping out the wrong-case name from `.git/packed-refs`, if it got in there.

---

<sup>1</sup>These paths are just defaults.  The new extra-worktree feature changes where some of these files are found, sometimes, and Git has environment variables that can override some of them.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, modern OSes do case-sensitivity on a per-file-system basis, rather than globally.  So where this says "if the OS is case-X" you can mentally substitute in "if the file system I'm using is case-X".

They may get it wrong.  Consider German, where the word "straße" (street) is written this way in lowercase, but in uppercase, becomes "STRASSE".  If we compare one character at a time with a case-insensitive *character* comparison, we have a problem when we hit the eszet ß as it converts to not one but two uppercase S-es.

This Python3 session shows that MacOS does indeed not believe that ß = SS:

```
>>> s
'straße'
>>> with open(s, 'w') as stream:
...     stream.write('street\n')
... 
7
>>> os.listdir()[10]
'file_абвгде'          # oops, that's one I was using for testing proftpd
>>> os.listdir()[30]   # should clean out my tmp dir more often ...
'straße'
>>> open('STRASSE')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'STRASSE'
>>> open('STRAßE').read()
'street\n'
```

It's things like this that sometimes convince me that computers should never interact with humans, and vice versa. :-)

<sup>3</sup>[Honey, what did you do to the cat?  It looks half-dead!  —Schrödinger's Wife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat)

<sup>4</sup>Older case-insensitive OSes—and at the time, this really was entire OSes—simply folded all names to one case, invariably uppercase.  Hence asking to create `masTER` actually created `MASTER` instead.  This is at least as wrong as case-preserving-yet-folding.  It is, however, less confusing: you can at least tell just how the OS will mangle your data.  The choice of case was rather shouty, of course.  Admittedly, in the days of the old uppercase-only Teletypes, they had an excuse.

Answer (score 1):

I restore the situation with :

```
git branch -m master tmp
git branch -m tmp master
```

But still no explanations on why this happens.

Comment: Case insensitive file systems. That can happen on Windows and on Mac too (depending on how it's configured). Be careful, if you pushed, you might have 2 folders on your remote branch, "master" and "masTER". Moreover, if you have 2 such folders, they will appear as a single one when you pull. Try checking through the web interface (GitHub) or from an OS with a case sensitive file system. Good luck.